# Retrieve value from list from google datastore python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I have a list in python which is product of a query to Google's Datastore, the list looks like this:

```
[<Entity('User', 1111) {'refreshToken': 'xxx', 'firstName': 'Bill', 'lastName': 'Last', 'accessToken': 'xxx', 'idToken': 'xxx', 'email': 'the_email'}>]
```

I need to extract the ID of the entity which is `1111`. I've tried the following with no success thus far:

```
result = list(query.fetch())
print(result[0][0]) #fails
print(result[0].Entity) #fails
print(result[0]['User']) #fails
print(result['User']) #fails
```

Any idea how I might be able to retrieve the ID value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/entity.html

```
entity = result[0]
print(entity.id)
```

Comment: This works and I'm not sure if it's because I'm extremely sleep deprived at the moment, but can you please bear with me and explain how this actually gets the id from the list?

Comment: The items in the list are instances of the "Entity" class.
Entity has property "id"

Comment: I see, thanks! I wish the docs were a bit more explicit about this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an Entity object back through the fetch query. You can access information like a dictionary.

```
# the line that said print(result["User"]) works
# the problem is that the key you used may not be the exact wording as in the data store entity
entity = list(query.fetch())[0]
print(entity['user']) #works just be careful for the key you pass in the []
```